# Unable to run xaml and c# example

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to run this example from this website for visual studio wpf.
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/creating-flowdocument-from-code-behind/. I copied the xaml code into MainWindow.xaml, and the c# i replaced MainWindow.xaml.cs with the c#. My MainWindow.xaml.cs looks like this

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Rich_text_controls
{
    public partial class CodeBehindFlowDocumentSample : Window
    {
        public CodeBehindFlowDocumentSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run("Hello, world!"));
            p.FontSize = 36;
            doc.Blocks.Add(p);

            p = new Paragraph(new Run("The ultimate programming greeting!"));
            p.FontSize = 14;
            p.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            p.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
            p.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
            doc.Blocks.Add(p);

            fdViewer.Document = doc;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it returns an error under FlowDocument which says "FlowDocument is a namespace but is used like a type".
Does anyone know where I have gone wrong? The main goal I am trying to achieve is writing a FlowDocument with c# instead of xaml.

Comment: Enter your xaml code. The xaml code is probably  problem

Comment: Is your project name `FlowDocument`? I used the above code to create the project which named `FlowDocument`,then I reproduced your problem. The code seems to have changed the namespace, but the name of the project still affects the namespace. Maybe you can create a new project instead of using `FlowDocument `as the project name.